# Can't get http only cookie in react app sent by flask app

Tags: reactjs, flask, cookies

I have a flask app which sends the refresh token in http only cookie. However in my client I cant receive it - it says

*"The Set-Cookie was blocked because it had "Secure" attribute but was not received over a secure connection. The Set-Cookie didnt specify a "Same Site" attribute and defaulted to Same-Site="Lax", and was blocked because it came from a cross site response which was not the response to a top level navigation. The Set-Cookie had to have been set with SameSite="None" to enable cross-site usage".*

** I have done it in node.js and it did work over an http connection, without any problem.

Here is what I have done in the flask app:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = APP_SECRET_KEY

JWTManager(app)

CORS(app, supports_credentials=True)
app.config['CORS_HEADERS'] = 'Content-Type'
app.config['JSON_SORT_KEYS'] = False
app.config['transports'] = 'websocket'


@app.after_request
def after_request(response):
    header = response.headers
    header['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = 'http://localhost:3000'
    header['Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'] = "true"
    header['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = "GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
    header['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = "Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With"
    return response


socketio = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins="http://localhost:3000", async_mode='threading')
```

The cookie set:

```
  res = server_response(msg=server_status_messages.LOGIN_SUCCESS, access_token=access_token)
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        expiration_date = now + datetime.timedelta(days=7)
        res.set_cookie('refresh_token', refresh_token, httponly=True, secure=True)
        return res
```

What am I doing wrong? what do I need to do in order to get the cookie from the response?